# Algorithm for removing edges in a connected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm

**The problem:**
You've got a connected, not directed graph. There are N vertices. You also have an array of structs:

```
struct Edge
{
     int a;
     int b;
}
```

The array StructArray represents all the edges. The size of the array is M. Find the minimum k so that after removing all the edges from StructArray except for those edges: [0...k-1], the graph is still connected.

**My idea**
I don't know how to handle this structure, so I am rebuilding it (it may be a very bad approach), to create an adjacency list:

```
vector < vector <int> > edges_list(N);
```

And now go from the end of StructArray and every time you want to delete an edge, you are checking in the edges_list:

```
edges_list[a].size() > 1 && edges_list[b].size() > 1;
```

What do you think about this solution? It's good/bad? You've got other? Maybe keeping the structure and not creating a new one?

Comment: Your approach looks okay to me.  If the number of edges were large, you *might* improve efficiency by converting one of your vectors to a map; but you probably won't do that, unless it later proves important to do.  Otherwise, your approach looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem incrementally rather than decrementally: starting from an empty graph, add the edges one by one until the graph is connected. Use a disjoint-set data structure as in [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to detect when there is exactly one connected component.

Comment: but for example if there are 1.000.000 edges and all of them are needed so that the graph could be connected, then the program should end immediately after testing the first edge (StructArray[m-1]).

Comment: @Randolph True, but the asymptotic running time of this approach is very close to linear anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of a very well known problem in graph theory, called the finding of a [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) problem. The variation is that in your problem the edges aren't weighted. In other words, all of your edges have the same weight, meaning your problem is, in a way, easier than the original one.

The two most commonly used algorithms to solve this problem are [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) and [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) (that David Eisenstat mentioned). Read about the problem and one of the algorithms (I personally think Prim's algorithm is more intuitive), and try to implement it (or find an existing implementation online, I'm sure there are plenty of them!).

Answer (score 0):

I think creating an adjacency list is a good idea.

However, I don't think the algorithm is correct.  Suppose you have A connected to B, and B connected to C, and C connected to D.  I think your algorithm would incorrectly think that it can delete the edge B to C, but this actually disconnects the graph.

This is a standard problem called finding a spanning tree.

One approach to fix it would be to start with any node and simply do a depth first search until all nodes have been reached.

Comment: You're right... Do you have an idea how to fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the minimum number of edges is always N - 1, (which is the number of edges in a tree)

So if you just want to find `k`, the answer is N - 1.

To find a valid set of edges, just use a simple [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) as those searches always form a connected tree (they never visit a vertex twice!)